# Insert data to specific column when dynamically building a table

Tags: javascript

I am getting a data object as JSON from the backend and I need to build a table dynamically:

```
data = {
   0: {'column1': 'some_data1', 'column2': 'some_data11', 'column3': 'some_data111'}
   1: {'column1': 'some_data2', 'column2': 'some_data22', 'column3': 'some_data222'}
   2: {'column1': 'some_data33', 'column2': 'some_data33', 'column3': 'some_data333'}
}
```

And I need to insert the data of `column2` in the third column, and `column3` in the middle.
But when I try to create cell, insert it and append the data, I get:

> Failed to execute 'insertCell' on 'HTMLTableRowElement': The value
> provided (2) is outside the range

I guess because the column doesn't exist yet, and when I try to insert the cell from column3 to the table's column 2 it throws the error:

```
let data = getData();
tbodyRef = document.getElementById("tableBody");
let newRow = tbodyRef.insertRow();

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
    if (key === 'column1') {
        newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
        cellText = document.createTextNode(value);
        newCell.appendChild(cellText);
    } else if (key === 'column2') {
        newCell = newRow.insertCell(2);
        cellText = document.createTextNode(value);
        newCell.appendChild(cellText);
    } else if (key === 'column3') {
        newCell = newRow.insertCell(1); 
        cellText = document.createTextNode(value);
        newCell.appendChild(cellText);
    }
}
```

So I believe that when I do `newCell = newRow.insertCell(2);` the third column (index 2) doesn't exist yet. What should I do? Should I first count the number of columns in the object (number of keys for example), then loop to create empty cells, then insert data? Or there is a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert the data as plain HTML - much faster than creating DOM elements, define the needed order of columns and map them into a rendered HTML. Also you can provide format functions for you column data:

```js
const data = {
   0: {'column1': 'some_data1', 'column2': 1688452200, 'column3': 'some_data111'},
   1: {'column1': 'some_data2', 'column2': 1688452200, 'column3': 'some_data222'},
   2: {'column1': 'some_data33', 'column2': 1688452200, 'column3': 'some_data333'},
};

const columns = {
  column1: null, 
  column3: null,
  column2: formatDate
};

document.querySelector('tbody').innerHTML = 
  Object
    .values(data)
    .map(row => '<tr><td>' + 
        Object.entries(columns).map(([name, fn]) => fn?.(row[name]) ?? row[name]).join('</td><td>') + 
      '</td></tr>'
    ).join('');
    
function formatDate(timestamp){
  const date = new Date(timestamp * 1000);
  date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + date.getTimezoneOffset());
  return date.toTimeString().slice(0, 8);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Awesome! I was sure that creating DOM elements is the preferred way. Is there then any scenario where creating DOM elements is better (I know it was not the question, but now I'm curious). Also, it works, thank you

Comment: Using HTML is preferred way if you have many resulting elements based on big data(for example a table). Otherwise rendering is slow. When you have a small job DOM is ok. When you use DOM there could be DOM layout recalculations also. If you want DOM - construct your inserted DOM in DocumentFragment and then insert the DOM into the page in 1 call. Also fast!

Comment: Got it, thank you! Btw, if I need to format one of the columns in a specific way using a function I made (I have a function that formats seconds to `H:m:s`, how can I call it inside the `map()`? Assuming it's `column2` for example and the function name is `formatTime(value)`, the following didn't work for me: `columns.map(column => { column === "column2" ? formatTime(row[column]) : row[column]; })`

Comment: @Stackerito i'll update my answer with the filters soon

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I didn't mention it at first

Comment: Wow this is some high level JavaScript, works like a charm. thank you

Comment: Of course, the upvote you have is from me :D (also marked the answer)